# Angular custom pipe to get number of items in checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-pipe

I am trying to count number of checkboxes that are checked. For that I added a custom pipe which is :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({
  name: "getSelected",
  pure: false
})
@Injectable()
export class GetSelectedCountPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) {}

  transform(items: any[]): any {
    // take out only selected values
    if (this.hostElement && this.hostElement.nativeElement) {
      const result = items.filter(item => item.selected === true).length;
      return result.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TS**:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'getSelectedCount',
})
export class GetSelectedCountPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[]): number {
    return items.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
      return previousValue + (currentValue.selected ? 1 : 0);
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Note that I've removed `@Injectable()` and changed `filter` to `reduce`.

**HTML**:

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">Total: {{ ARRAY | getSelectedCount }}</span>
```

**PS**: Don't forget to add the `@Pipe` to a `@NgModule#declarations`.

Comment: why not `items.filter(x=>x.selected).length?`

Comment: @Eliseo For no specific reason. Just wanted to do it with `reduce` :)

Answer (score -1):

You shall return `string` in the pipe to be drawn as in the following Demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iaswzg